# In-memory Flask session storage

Tags: flask, session

How to store the flask session inside memory/RAM until the code is running. If you don't give the session type (as there is no current interface available for in-memory), the app quits with:

> "The session is unavailable because no secret key was set.  Set the secret_key on the application to something unique and secret."

This behaviour is described on official docs as:

> If you do not configure a different `SESSION_TYPE`, this (**NullSessionInterface)** will be used to generate nicer error messages. Will allow read-only access to the empty session but fail on setting.

I tried to set the secret key, but nothing worked well. Obviously i can do the same with python dicts but then I will have to manage the cookies manually.